# How do I combine functions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python code that should convert str to int and find the sum of the inputs. Here's the code:

```
def convert_add():
    strings=[]
    n=int(input('Enter the list size: '))
    for i in range(0,n):
        print('Enter a string:',i)
        item=(input())
        if item==str:
            strings.append(len(item))
            print(sum(strings))
        else:
            strings.append(int(item))
            print(sum(strings))
convert_add()
```

So here's the thing, when I run this code it sums up the length of the strings I input, but I also want it to sum up integers. Since its a len function inputting a number(int) does the same thing it does to a string, it counts the figures, but I want an output of lets say 10 and 20 to be 30 and not 4. I have tried using the if statement and it's not working, i.e if item==str use the len fn else it sums. I am still a beginner and would love to know if there is a way I can combine them. Thanks.

Comment: You are telling it to append the length of the string. Instead, append the string as a number: `strings.append(len(item))` --> `strings.append(int(item))`

Comment: I have tweaked the code a little bit by including the if statements that I was using to try and make the idea I have in my head work. However, only one of the statements is working. Is there a way it can be both, is the 'if item==str' wrong?

Comment: In this case, `item` will never be equal to `str`, as `str` is a builtin *type*.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  The return type from the `input` function is always of type `str`.  Do a bit of research in detecting if a string contains only digits, or alpha characters.  (I believe that’s what you’re trying to accomplish here(?))

Comment: I am trying to get an output from the sum of length of strings that I append or the sum of integers that I append. I'll do a little more digging. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine.
Note that for input combined at the same time, for example 'str' and 10,
you will get an aggregate value of 13.

```
def convert_add():
    strings = []
    n = int(input('Enter the list size: '))
    for i in range(n):
        item = input(f'Enter a string {i + 1}: ')
        try:
            strings.append(int(item))
        except ValueError:
            # That's not an int
            strings.append(len(item))
        print(sum(strings))

convert_add()
```

Comment: Wow, this is even better than I'd hoped. Thanks alot :-)